# Blazor - an alternate approach to sharing data between pages

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

We have a non-trivial blazor wasm app prototyped and are about to refactor it for production.  There is a lot of complexity entailed in sharing objects between pages.  We are thinking of abandoning the built-in routing in favor of an approach where each "page" is just a component, and selectively rendered based on some state variable.  See the code fragment below where C1 and C2 are components.  Is this a bad idea?

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
@switch (currentCount)
{
    case 1:
    {
        <C1></C1>
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        <C2></C2>
        break;
    }

    //more "page cases" go here
    
    default:
    {
        <p> No component</p>
        break;
    }
}

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the best way is use a service to store the data, check, e.g. https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/blazor-singleton-pass-data-between-pages/

Comment: Thanks Eliseo.  Our prototype already has an elaborate "AppState" singleton.  It just seems like a fragile way to communicate complex objects between pages. e.g. Page1 sets a bunch of AppState values that Page 2 needs, then navigates to Page 2.  What if some other event handler changes the AppState unexpectedly?  It just reminds me of passing parameters using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd investigate Fluxor for state management... way more powerful yet gets a bit o time to use properly.

https://betweentwobrackets.dev/posts/2020/06/state-management-with-blazor-using-fluxor-part-1/

Comment: Thanks.  We looked a Fluxor quite a while ago, and decided it was not mature enough for production at the time. Looks like things have improved, and we will take another look.  Thanks for the tip!  This does not really answer the question though.  Any thoughts on that?